# Calculate harmonics for a set of data extracted from images

Tags: signal-processing

I am implementing a method known as trace transform for image analysis. The algorithm extracts a lot of features of an image (in my case features pertained to texture) using a set of transforms on the values of the pixels. Here is a paper describing the algorithm: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&ved=0CGoQFjAHOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpdf.aminer.org%2F000%2F067%2F295%2Ftexture_classification_with_thousands_of_features.pdf&ei=lV9cUez_GYrx2QX-voCgDw&usg=AFQjCNEbCd8GBm4X8V4vk0PYyQwPZPlWyg&sig2=KTtvd1XxtvuUpCDeBzUu4A (sorry for the long link)

The algorithm finally constructs a "triple feature" which is a number that characterizes the image and was calculated by applying a first set of transforms on the pixel values extracted by all the tracing lines going through the image at all angles. On the paper you can see this description starting on page 2, Figure 1 shows an abstraction of such a tracing line which is defined by its angle (phi) and the distance (d) of the line from the center of the image. So we can describe each tracing line by the pair (phi,d).

Now on the next page on the paper (page 3) we have Table 1 which is the set of functionals that is applied to the pixel values extracted by the tracing lines. Each of these functionals applied to all the tracing lines generates another representation of the image. Then another set of functionals (those that appear on Table 2 on page 4) are applied to the new representation of the image along the columns which is basically along parameter d generating, this way, another new representation of the image.

Finally another set of functionals is applied to this last representation which is an array of values over parameter phi which was the angle parameter (that means we have 360 values describing the image, one for each angle of the tracing lines). You can see these functionals in the paper on Table 3 page 4.

Now some of this last set of functionals that have to be applied to the last representation of the image over parameter phi need to calculate the harmonics of this set of 360 values. First I need to calculate the first harmonic and then the amplitude and phase of the first through fourth harmonic but I don't know how to do this.

I hope this explains it better. You can read the first couple of pages of the paper since it's probably better explained there. And figure 1 makes it clear what I mean by tracing lines and the representation of each line by the (phi,d) pair.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more information. At a guess it sounds like you are doing discrete cosine compression or something similar. What algorithm are you trying to implement? What have you tried? "Harmonics" might refer to integer multiples of some (spatial) frequency, but without more context it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question with more info. It'll take me sometime though. Thanks

Comment: I hope this explains it better.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I did but no one answered it... I'm going to try again. Thanks

Comment: Interesting paper. I don't understand what they mean either - I assume they cover it in one of the references to trace transforms, though. Searching for 'circus functional harmonic' delivers some other papers, mostly the same authors though.